# How to sort tuples in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have a dataframe that consists of a column of tuples as shown:

```
pid         aid                   
0000000F    (0BDEAC61, 288E046F)    
00000017    (7795AF0D, 4A259AFA, 7DA84B6E)  
00000019    (8123B8CF, 3A25A1FE)    
00000025    (28045D98, 8043B6E5, 81195E5D)  
0000003A    (7D566708, 7F5583AE)
```

I want to sort the values in each of the tuples so the result would be as follows:

```
pid         aid                   
0000000F    (0BDEAC61, 288E046F)    
00000017    (4A259AFA, 7795AF0D, 7DA84B6E)  
00000019    (3A25A1FE, 8123B8CF)    
00000025    (28045D98, 8043B6E5, 81195E5D)  
0000003A    (7D566708, 7F5583AE)
```

I know that I can loop through them one at a time and sort as follows:

```
z = list(eval(df.aid.iloc[0]))
z.sort()
```

But that would take a long time as it's a huge dataframe (over 4 million). Is there a faster method.

I also tried:

```
df.aid = df.aid.apply(lambda x: list(eval(x)).sort())
```

but I got `"None"`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You get `None` because `.sort()` sorts the list in place. Instead, you *could* do `lambda x: sorted(eval(x))` but `eval` is evil and should never be used. I'm not sure why you can't simply do `lambda x: sorted(x)` (or just `.apply(sorted)` with no `lambda` at all)

Comment: Unless the values in `aid` are strings and not tuples, then that's a whole different question

Comment: What return `print (df['aid'].head().apply(type))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think simpliest is use `list comprehension` if no `NaN`s values:

```
#import ast
#one possible way for convert string to tuples
#df['aid'] = df['aid'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

print (df['aid'].head().apply(type))
0    <class 'tuple'>
1    <class 'tuple'>
2    <class 'tuple'>
3    <class 'tuple'>
4    <class 'tuple'>
Name: aid, dtype: object

df['aid'] = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in df['aid']]
print (df)
        pid                             aid
0  0000000F            (0BDEAC61, 288E046F)
1  00000017  (4A259AFA, 7795AF0D, 7DA84B6E)
2  00000019            (3A25A1FE, 8123B8CF)
3  00000025  (28045D98, 8043B6E5, 81195E5D)
4  0000003A            (7D566708, 7F5583AE)
```

Or:

```
df['aid'] = df['aid'].apply(sorted)
print (df)
        pid                             aid
0  0000000F            [0BDEAC61, 288E046F]
1  00000017  [4A259AFA, 7795AF0D, 7DA84B6E]
2  00000019            [3A25A1FE, 8123B8CF]
3  00000025  [28045D98, 8043B6E5, 81195E5D]
4  0000003A            [7D566708, 7F5583AE]
```