# In Pandas DataFrame when each cell is an array sort each subarray

Tags: python, pandas

To illustrate my question, consider the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'player': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice'], 
                   'hand': [['two','ace'], ['queen','king'], ['three','five']]})
```

I would like to sort each hand array.
I've tried using lamdas orlooping through df using iterrow, but I couldn't get either to work.

BONUS: The reason I want it sorted is so I could do a groupby on that column to identify all players having same hand. Perhaps, there is a more direct way of doing it.

Comment: Your data is not tabular. I doubt that a dataframe is the appropriate abstraction for your data if you wish to keep it in its current shape.

Comment: Kindly post your expected output dataframe

Comment: @orlp what other abstraction would allow to easily do a groupby on the subarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `apply(sorted)`:

```
df['hand'] = df['hand'].apply(sorted)
```

Output:

```
  player           hand
0    Bob     [ace, two]
1   Jane  [king, queen]
2  Alice  [five, three]
```

This won't allow you to group as lists are not hashable.

If your goal is to group or compare, **and the cards are unique**, you could also use a `frozenset`:

```
df['hand'] = df['hand'].apply(frozenset)
```

Or, if you want to consider duplicated cards (e.g, ace+ace), sort and convert to tuple:

```
df['hand'] = df['hand'].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)))
```

Output:

```
  player           hand
0    Bob     (two, ace)
1   Jane  (king, queen)
2  Alice  (three, five)
```

Then you can `groupby` hand to list the players with the same hand:

```
df.groupby('hand')['player'].apply(list)
```

Output:

```
hand
(ace, two)         [Bob]
(five, three)    [Alice]
(king, queen)     [Jane]
Name: player, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

I will do `explode` ,for your next step , you can just `groupby` the hand `agg` the player

```
df.explode('hand').groupby('hand').player.agg(list)
hand
ace        [Bob]
five     [Alice]
king      [Jane]
queen     [Jane]
three    [Alice]
two        [Bob]
Name: player, dtype: object
```

Comment: This will get us who has each card, but how would you tell who all have the same hand?

Answer (score 0):

I think that using `sorted` is one of the best *options*, and in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49348396/how-to-sort-tuples-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe) it is also raised.

```
>>> df['hand'] = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in df['hand']]
>>> df
  player           hand
0    Bob     (ace, two)
1   Jane  (king, queen)
2  Alice  (five, three)
```